# Bootstrap and resizable splitter

Tags: angularjs, resizable, splitter

I am new to Angularjs and Bootstrap ad been trying hard to get the resizable                 splitters to work.
I have sidebar which is collapsible and 4 grid text area. I need to have horizontal and vertical splitter so that the user can resize. I have tried the below splitters

- `ui-layout`
- `Angular pane splitter`
- `bg-splitter`

I am still not able to get the resizing to work. Has anyone got Bootstrap and splitters to work together?? I would appreciate if you could share your plunker example.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: Here is working plunker for 'angular-resizable', http://codepen.io/Reklino/pen/raRaXq/. But when I use it along with boostrap, its neither showing the splitter or resizing.

Comment: With 'ui-layout' I'm getting TypeError: element.splitPane is not a function.http://embed.plnkr.co/EZwUR4/preview

Comment: In case of 'angular-flex-spiltter', i am able to get the Splitter in the UI but resizing is not working:( . I tried the example code of https://github.com/rodeschen/angular-flex-splitter

Comment: Finally got the UI-Layout to work with ng-view:)